# Finding all similar pairs in a database

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this.

```
A    B
_    _

1   100
1   101 
2   105
2   105
2   104
3   106
```

I need to output all A values which have the B value occurring the same number of times. Thus, expected output:

```
A
_

1
3
```

This is because `1 - 100` and `1 - 101` appears once each. `2` is infidel because `2 - 105` appears twice but `2 - 104` only once. `3` is okay, because it has just one item i.e `106`.

My solution so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t1
JOIN Table t2
ON t2.A = t1.A
WHERE t1.B = t2.B;
```

Comment: *2 is infidel* - Come again?

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN on something equals something and another thing doesn't equal another thing WHERE something IS NULL - but perhaps I've misunderstood the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Write a query that returns just the pairs that have a repetition count of `1` using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`. Then use that as a subquery so you can return just the distinct `A` values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A
FROM (SELECT A, B
      FROM Table
      GROUP BY A, B
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS x
```